# How do I write and compile a Apache Handler?

Tags: apache, web, webserver, handler

So how do I write a handler. Say I had a .bob file on my server. A custom extension and format. Inside the .bob file I might have `echo 'Hi';` I want to write a handler so that when a visitor goes to mywebsite.com/test.bob they are presented with a html form that has the text Hi. How do I do it and how will it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the following documentation

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/developer/
- http://threebit.net/tutorials/apache2_modules/tut1/tutorial1.html

In ubuntu you can install apache2-doc

> $ sudo apt-get install apache2-doc

This will provide you with the same documentation

- http://localhost/manual/en/index.html
- http://localhost/manual/en/developer/index.html

The developer documentation has some topics which would be of interest to you.

- [Request Processing in Apache 2.0](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/developer/request.html)